# How to set condition rules

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I have coded this buy/sell strategy in Pine Editor/TradingView:

```
buy_condition= a<b
sell_condition= a>b

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=buy_condition)
strategy.exit("L_Out", "Long", profit=1000, loss=500)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=sell_condition)
strategy.exit("S_Out", "Short", profit=1000, loss=500)
```

While in a long or short position, it changes position when opposite condition become true, but i want it to keep in position until it hits profit or stop loss. Then it can enter any position that fits again. How can i code this rule?

Comment: Hi Onur Kiris, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mre] to help us reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to replace your:

```
buy_condition= a<b
sell_condition= a>b
```

by:

```py
def buy_condition(a, b):
    return a < b


def sell_condition(a, b):
    return a > b
```

When you create `buy_condition`, it compute the result at this moment, not later.
So if `a<b` at this line, it will always be `True` later.

If you pass those functions to your `strategy.exit` method, you have to call the function with somethink like `by_condition(a, b)`.

Comment: When i type 'def' in Pine Editor, it didnt recognize it. Below link is about 'Pine Script language reference manual'. Can you check it for your guidance?                                                                                          https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/

Comment: i just added  'strategy.position_size==0' into the condition and it worked